# Javascript giving a TypeError variable is undefined for code (photo gallery) run on server. Same code works locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, undefined, typeerror

i'm putting together a personal website as a portfolio and i'm having trouble getting a photo gallery to work. I found a free Javascript gallery (http://ettrics.com/lab/demo/material-photo-gallery/) that I decided to implement. When putting the page together locally, the javascript runs no problem, however when I upload the page to the site (which already has plenty of other javascript running) I get the following error when scrolling on the page, or when trying to 'fullscreen' one of the images by clicking on it:

```
TypeError: this._fullImgs is undefined
```

I tried to isolate the issue and found that a line of code was executing differently on the server, than locally, the excerpt is below:

```
Gallery.prototype._loadFullImgsDone = function() {

        var imgLoad = imagesLoaded(this._fullBox);
        imgLoad.on('done', function(instance) {
            var imgArr = instance.images;

            this._fullImgs = [];
            this._fullImgDimensions = [];
            this._fullImgsTransforms = [];

            for (var i = 0, ii = imgArr.length; i < ii; i++) {
                var rect = imgArr[i].img.getBoundingClientRect();
                this._fullImgs.push(imgArr[i].img);
                this._positionFullImgs.call(this, imgArr[i].img, i);
                this._fullImgDimensions.push(rect);
            }

            this._fullImgsLoaded = true;
        }.bind(this));
    };
```

I have found that the images are being found from their source location, however

```
imgLoad.on('done', function(instance) {
...
```

executes differently. The site is located at http://http://samueller.tech/photo-best.html id anybody would like to see for themselves the error I am getting.

Thanks in advance, i'm at a complete loss of how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing (on that site) the `resizeHandler` is getting called before the images are loaded

```
Gallery.prototype._handleScroll = debounce(function() {
    this._resetFullImg.call(this);  
}, 25);

Gallery.prototype._handleResize = function() {
    this._resetFullImg.call(this);
};
```

Then `this._resetFullImg` fails because there are no images loaded yet which is why `this._fullImgs` is empty.  The code seems to have another variable called `_fullImgsLoaded` and probably the `_resetFullImg` method should do nothing if images haven't been loaded.

You could try adding that like this:

```
// in material-photo-gallery.js line 1379
Gallery.prototype._resetFullImg = function() {

    if (!this._fullImagesLoaded) {
      return
    }

    this._fullImgsTransforms = [];

    for (var i = 0, ii = this._fullImgs.length; i < ii; i++) {
       ...
```

I don't know how this will affect the reset of the gallery code, but it might work.  It makes some sense that on your production system, the page load time (with extra JS and stuff) is such that these events might get called before things are ready which is something you don't see locally.

good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Your code solved the errors when scrolling, but the images still give the same type error when they are clicked. This time on line 1437 in material-photo-gallery.js

Comment: Sadly, it looks like the issue may be deeper than I can figure out without being able to really debug.  It appears that the 'done' event is never fired which means the system never thinks all the full images are there, though it appears that they've loaded.  Perhaps the guard clause that I've added is causing issues because the plugin is trying to do async loading of the big pictures.  I would suggest submitting your question to the gallery author and see if they can shed some light on things.

Comment: I have one last trick up my sleeve and then I will do that. I'm going to try manually creating and adding the images to '_fullImgs' to see if that works. Since this is just personal I don't mind having to adjust it every time the pictures change (which won't be often). Thanks again